# Detect IP blocking or blacklisting

Tags: networking, ip, blacklist

Unable to access a cloud server (Windows) from a particular public IP provided by the ISP. Tried to PING, tracert, telnet everything, nothing worked. No deny rule mentioned in the firewall. Properly accessible from any other IP or location. There is no option to use another public IP as the ISP provided only one IP here.
I suspect that the IP is getting blocked or blacklisted in Hosting provider's network. But according to them there is nothing found against that IP. I tried tracert, which clearly shows that the request entering into the providers network before getting continuous RTO but still they are not convinced. Everything else are working perfectly from that IP.

Any tool which can points the actual reason. Tried 'Wireshark', but unable to pin point.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended but you can use 3rd party port scanning tools such as:
http://www.t1shopper.com/tools/port-scan/ 
as a starter.
The basic suggestion is to verify the windows machine FW rules and to allow access from everywhere(just for the test period) and then verify that the service is accessible from couple places at the same time.
Do not assume it's the hosting provider since it can be other points in the way!
Also what do you mean by "Everything else are working perfectly from that IP" like from other IP addresses or any other service on the same windows machine and from the same IP you are having trouble with?
Also it depends on what service you are running on the windows machine.
Some Routers for example do not support out of the box the usage of VPN tunnels NAT.
Also what Wireshark showed you? do you get a three way handshake?

Comment: Generally we use SQL server database installed on cloud server and that database is being used for several locations. There is a cloud server (Windows) having Public IP say 222.111.555.444 and one location having an fixed Public IP, say 111.222.444.555. This location is not able to connect that database, while other locations do not have any issue. The affected location was OK few days back also. When I did further investigation I found, the server can't be reached neither by PING nor Tracert.

Comment: The Tracert result clearly shows, the last 2 hops which replied are from the hosting provider but after that continuous RTO coming. On the other hand I can successfully reach to the cloud server IP 222.111.555.44 from any other location or via any other ISP. The cloud server is managed by us only. I have checked the Windows Firewall there and every thing from every where is set allowed. This location does not have any issue with other Internet activity using the IP 111.222.444.555.

Comment: I think the issue is a routing issue and not FW.
You can safely contact the ISP and tell them that couple days ago it worked fine and from any other ISP the service is fine but from theirs not.
you can also tracert from the windows server to the IP and see whatever happens there.
It can unleash couple hints on the matter.
Also try to ping from the windows server to another subnet of the specific ISP you are using at this place.

Comment: I have contacted both ISP and provider, but both of them denying. 
I tried tracert from the server to that IP, it is not replying after a certain hop. Getting same result from any other locations also. Might be ICMP is blocked due to security reason.
That's why I need to run some test to identify the problem. Will Wireshark help me here? What should I observe there?

Comment: Sorry that they both deny it.
Indeed there is an option that you got to the wrong and unqualified person.
It can be caused by middle way network operator or another thing.
You can leave the ICMP level and move to port 80 level just to test another approach.
Put a web service(there are many tiny ones) on the server and try to contact the service.
You will most likely have more help from anyone when you will state that you have a website that you cannot access and only from this connection while from work or from cafe internet etc.